# sass variable interpolation in each loop

Tags: css, sass, scss-lint

I am trying to use variable inside each loop but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$font-size-40: .5rem;
$font-size-50: .625rem;
$font-size-60: .75rem;
$fonts: 40 50 60;

@each $font in $fonts {
    .font-size-#{$font} {
        font-size: $font-size-#{$font};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made it this way. It's working fine with key value approach.

```
$font-size-40: .5rem;
$font-size-50: .625rem;
$font-size-60: .75rem;

$fonts: (
    '40': $font-size-40,
    '50': $font-size-50,
    '60': $font-size-60,
);

@each $font, $prop in $fonts {
    .font-size-#{$font} {
        font-size: #{$prop};
    }
}
```

But still want to know why we cant use it like:- `$font-size-#{$font}`

Answer (score 0):

```
$fonts: (
    'font-size-40' : 40,
    'font-size-50' : 50,
    'font-size-60' : 60
);

@each $name, $font in $fonts {
    .#{$name} {
        font-size: #{$font};
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers generally aren't clear.